# Output an Array using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I need to create an `Array` asking the user for 5 values to enter.

They must enter city names (strings) and I need to create that using a `for` loop.

Then I need to output that information using another `for` loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Declare the variables
var cities= array(SIZE);
var SIZE = 5;
var index = 0;
var BR = "<br />";

// Create the for loop to prompt the user
for(index = 0; index < SIZE ; index++) {
  cities= prompt("Please enter the cities!");
}

//Output the array information
for( /* ? */ ) {
  document.write(cities[SIZE]+ " was the city you entered" + BR);
}
```

I don't know what to put between the `for()` to output that information. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're not adding to the `cities` - you're replacing the array with a string, each time through the loop. You want to use `push()` instead.

And don't output `cities[SIZE]` - that will be past the end of the array. Loop through (just like on input) and output `cities[index]`.

```js
//Declare the variables
var SIZE = 5;
var cities = new Array(SIZE);   // JS is case-sensitive
var index = 0;
var BR = "<br />";

//Create the for loop to prompt the user
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
  cities[index] = prompt("Please enter the cities!");
}

//Output the array information
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
  document.write(cities[index] + " was the city you entered" + BR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul is right. In the first loop you directly set cities variable to the input entered by the user. Also you don't need to set the Array size. Best practice is to use brackets. Shortened version could be:

```
//Declare the variables
var size = 5,
    cities = [];

//Create the for loop to prompt the user
for (var index = 0; index < size; index++) {
   cities.push(prompt("Please enter the cities!"));
}

//Output the array information
for (var index in cities) {
  document.write(cities[index] + " was the city you entered <br />");
}
```